# Gmap.net, marker Clustering

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

Has anyone done anything with marker clustering in Gmap.net?
I have a heap of markers that I need to aggregate with one overall marker containing the number of markers under it.
Can't think of a way to do this.
I'm using Windows Forms.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Do you mean you want to represent several markers as one when you are zoomed out?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Then when you zoom in and the individual markers become visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would hook into the gmapControl.OnMapZoomChangedEvent and then write some logic to manage your markers inside that delegate e.g.

```
    gMapControl.OnMapZoomChanged += GMapControl_OnMapZoomChanged;

    private void GMapControl_OnMapZoomChanged()
    {
        if (gMapControl.Zoom > 10)
        {
            // split markers
        }
        else
        {
            // group markers
        }
    }
```